# Number of ways to divide students into groups of 4 with additional conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Ok, I have this question:

[image]

I have the answers available but I'm struggling to get my around a few parts of the answer.

So far I believe:

Q1a)
$(4n)!$ dictates the number possible ways of ordering all of the students
Dividing by $n!$ puts the students into groups of $4$,   $(4n)! / n!$.
With that I need to cancel the repeat combinations so that I don't have duplicate groups which I do by dividing by $4!^n$

Thus $$q1a =  \dfrac{(4n)!}{ n!  (4!)^n }$$

**I know the answer is correct, but I'm not sure if my logic is correct?**

Then on q1b)

The answer is $(4n)! / (4!)^n$      - Is this due to the rule of permutations with repetitions where it equals $\dfrac{n!}{ q_1!q_2! \cdots q_k!}$    where $q_1 + q_2 + \dots + q_k = n$ ?

Comment: ad a): $n!$ is the possible orderings of the n groups. And $(4!)^n$ is the possible orderings of 4n students into n groups. This would be my interpretation. ad b) the reasoning sounds good.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and try [writing better titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the row

$$\underbrace{a_1a_2a_3a_4|a_5a_6a_7a_8|a_9a_{10}a_{11}a_{12}|\ldots|a_{4n-3}a_{4n-2}a_{4n-1}a_{4n}}_{n \text{ groups}}$$

You can see $n$ groups, each consisting of $4$ people.

All the $a$'s can be re-arranged in $(4n)!$ ways.

$a),b)$ Each group consists of $4$, and it doesn't matter in which order those $4$ people appear inside the groups, hence we divide $(4n)!$ by $\underbrace{4!\cdot 4!\cdots 4!}_{n}=(4!)^n$.

$a)$ It does **not** matter in which order those groups appear in the row, hence we additionally divide the numbers of ways by $n!$ and the answer is $\frac{(4n)!}{n!(4!)^n}$.

$b)$ It **does** matter in which order those groups appear in the row - we can say that the first group that appears in the row has a project $h_1$, the one that appears second - project $h_2$, and so on. Hence we do **not** divide by $n!$ as we do in the $a)$ case. Hence the answer is just $\frac{(4n)!}{(4!)^n}$.

$c_1)$ If we assume each group has its own project, then the order in which people appear inside the groups **does** matter, and the order in which the groups appear in the row **does** matter as well, hence it is just $(4n)!$.

$c_2)$ However, if we assume each group does **not** have its own project, as in $a)$, then the order in which groups appear in the row does **not** matter, hence we divide $(4n)!$ by $n!$, since there are $n$ groups. The order in which people appear inside the groups **does** matter, hence we're left with $\frac{(4n)!}{n!}$, we do not divide anything by $(4!)^n$.